# How to insert rows in reverse order?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, row, sql-insert

What I'm trying to do is copy the rows of one table to another table. I have 2 choices to copy them on direct order or reverse order. I have no problem with direct order. But I couldn't insert them in reverse order. I'm trying to do it with ORDER BY DESC, but DESC isn't working with subqueries. So I'm doing it with statement. And SELECT returns me in reverse order by PRIMARY KEY. But data in DB my_db_copy inserted in direct order. How can I insert them in reverse order?

```
set @Query1=Concat ('INSERT INTO my_db_copy.test1 SELECT * FROM my_db.test1 
ORDER BY ', (   SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db')
  AND (TABLE_NAME = 'test1')
  AND (COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI')), ' DESC');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @Query1;
  EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: What is the resulting value of `@Query1` here?  When you remove the `INSERT` clause from that resulting query and just execute the `SELECT` with its `ORDER BY`, what is the observed order of the results?  How is that different from what you're expecting?  The code you're showing us is a few steps removed from the question you're asking.

Comment: @David if I remove INSERT from set it will show the reverse order, but it won't be inserted in that reverse order.

Comment: Why do you think that?  If that's the order of the results then that's the order in which they're being used.  In what order are you later *selecting* the results of the destination table to observe them?  If you're not specifying one then no order is guaranteed.  It sounds like you're making assumptions here.

Comment: @David to see the result I select them without any order, I mean I don't do order by. what is the default order for queries without any order by?

Comment: While it's not guaranteed, the "default" order is usually very likely to be the primary key, as that's usually the clutered index and the physical order in which records are stored on the disk by the database engine.

Comment: @rdhd queries without order by return lines in any order the DBMS thinks convenient at the time of execution. It might be anything and it might even change from one execution of the query to next.

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as "reversing" the order.

You *can* assign values to an auto-incremented column to specify a particular ordering.

If you want results in a particular order when you issue a query, then you need to explicitly include an `order by`.  There is no other way to guarantee a result set in a particular order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but if I have the table with ID 1 2 3 4 5, but if I want to copy them into another table with ID 5 4 3 2 1. How to do so?

Comment: @rdhd . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with sample data and desired results.  But remember the first message here:  tables are *unordered*.